# Delegate type definitions to implementation

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to correct type the following object. Here `key` is a key of an interface, `T` is either string, number, or boolean, and `E` is an object of some keys and string values. The issue is that `E` is different for each entry of the object, and I want to keep the type information for each of them.

```
{
   [key]: (errorMessage?: E) => Validation<T, E>
}
```

For example, I could have something like this.

```js
interface StudentSchema {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  country: string;
  age: number;
}

interface Validation<T, E> {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  validations: (errorMessages? E) => SchemaValidation<T>;
}

interface SchemaValidation<T> {
   setIsRequired(message?: string) => SchemaValidation<T>;
   setMatches(regex: any, message?: string) => SchemaValidation<T>;
   setMax(max: number, message?: string) => SchemaValidation<T>;
   isValid (data: T) => boolean;
}

class StringSchemaValidation extends SchemaValidation<string> { /* ... */ }
class NumberSchemaValidation extends SchemaValidation<number> { /* ... */ }

const StudentValidations: Record<keyof StudentSchema, Validation<T, E>> = {
  name: {
    foo: 'AAA',
    bar: 1,
    validation: (errorMessages?: { required: string }): SchemaValidation<string> =>
      new SchemaValidation()
      .setIsRequired(errorMessages?.required),
  },
  id: {
    foo: 'BBB',
    bar: 2,
    validation: (errorMessages?: { required: string; match: string; max: (max: number) => string }): SchemaValidation<string> =>
       new SchemaValidation()
      .setIsRequired(errorMessages?.required)
      .setMatches(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/, errorMessages?.match)
      .setMax(30, errorMessage?.max),
  },
  country: {
    foo: 'CCC',
    bar: 3,
    validation: (errorMessages?: { required: string }): SchemaValidation<string> =>
      new SchemaValidation()
      .setIsRequired(errorMessage?.required),
  },
  age: {
    foo: 'DDD',
    bar: 4,
    validation: (errorMessages?: { required: string }): SchemaValidation<number> =>
      new NumberSchemaValidation()
      .setIsRequired(errorMessage?.required),
  },
};
```

First of all, this doesn't compile because I'm not specifying `E` for `StudentValidations`, but I don't know what to put because it's different for each entry. I can use `any` or something similar, but then I'll lose the type information when I access the `validations` function.

What I want is to essentially "delegate" the type declaration to the implementation, but this doesn't seem to be possible. Is there a way to achieve what I want? Or, maybe there's a different way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you modify this code to constitute a [mcve] that doesn't depend on "yup" unless your question is specifically about that library?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgK4BMLlQgCwgFs5kBvAKGRuRDmIgC5kBnMKUAcwG5rbgWFiAzEARtD61kCAPYZwUAJ4sxs2QBsIcEHwC+ySpVCRYiFADU4GwXDDBZIADwAVADTIAogD4K-GjDqLOycILz+yABu1rb2jqwsABTQULJQALIQrKxwXFkA-CyeAJTIALy+LvqUciDsUdas5ciu3omlFS0AqsgQAB6QIFhN5MgA2gDSyKDIANYQSrIwyC4AuixWNlh2Ds4uk6seOkq+em3RGulwAA4sXR2+F1fXfLX12ZtNZQ0arE7o2FwYHwRFIbWKr3iYDQmBw4E2sV2XzYrE+iSo0kELAx0logVkLAARIS3BFpBdEfEkik0plsrkCsJRBIoGNVg9kMkoKkMlkcnkmgAfQXjdkAOi0YTABAielJ0jkCg4Kj8uLxQWQxPlap+lLq1MKdGZ0A5AEJTRBZdqaPRGNiyeqCZqSQ6aBTtnF9ZyIIa1JptCAOcTZUY9MVKEA) works for you?

Comment: @jcalz You can ignore/replace yup completely. It doesn't matter what it is. That example you provided works!  But, I want to be able to pass a different interface to ssVals. Currently, it's hardcoded to StudentSchema.. . Is it possible to generalize it to for other ones? I couldn't figure that out, either. (This looks a bit like magic to me).

Comment: Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDbACZzMAexAB4AVAGmQFEA+ZAbwChkXkYCCAuZAZzClABzANzNWAN0w48hED24AKaFAJQAshB484gzQH5uVAJTIAvHVKiAvowRE+ySRh5nkZGgpPm3AVWQQAD0gQbBd6ZABtAGlkUGQAawgATwIYZFIAXW50LFx8IjJojMo4ECS6Kw8nNTgAB24fLzpqutFGRlBIWEQUADEOBjEWEDgAWwhuPgEQESHY7G4QAFdRgCNoa1t7MDYOHJdTR0weYn6CDyMFJlZ57nD2LmQAIifKJ2l8uUUIA2RltegEQyTWQSmQAB9wZFgQA6DAQGZgAAWyCs5DmI3Gd12jxebykeVk8lBP24qw48NKIJeqMYViM7U60HgSGQACE4FBBjdVnAAF5kikQUqiG4ARyWAW4ABE8BBNnY5DteVB9q4nCcOVALlc5ryBQwcdw8UdcjJ7IoAr9-usoCCAIT2gKo9HiyXYh7G16mj5ExRJX5TIQgkAQADuyFlkAUSQhUJeJhs9KAA)?

Comment: I'd be happy to write this up as an answer if you'd change the example to be something answerable without an apparent library dependency.  Otherwise the first half of my answer would be setting up the question code myself so that I can then provide the code that answers it.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code. It was really just an example, and did not matter what it was, but hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's two pieces to the problem here.  In `Validation<T, E>` derived from an interface like `StudentSchema`, it has the same keys as `StudentSchema`, and for each key `K`, the `T` type is the type of the corresponding property `StudentSchema[K]`.  This part is a perfect use case for [mapped types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).  This would look something like:

```
/* type ValidationFor<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Validation<T[K], ...>}; */
/* type ValidationForStudentSchema = ValidationFor<StudentSchema>; */
```

where the `...` is the as-yet-unknown thing we want to do for `E`.  What you *could* do here is come up with another object type `E` that has the same keys as `StudentSchema` whose properties are used to plug into the `E` in `Validation`.  It would look something like:

```
type ValidationFor<T, E extends Record<keyof T, any>> = 
   { [ K in keyof T ]: Validation<T[K], E[K]> };

type ValidationForStudentSchema<E extends Record<keyof StudentSchema, any>> =
   ValidationFor<StudentSchema, E>  */
```

And then your example `StudentValidations` would be of the following type:

```
const StudentValidations: ValidationFor<StudentSchema, {
    name: { required: string },
    country: { required: string; },
    age: { required: string; },
    id: { required: string; match: string; max: (max: number) => string; }
}> = ...;
```

But this would require either that we explicitly write out that `E` object type, or try to get the compiler to infer it, neither of which are particularly fun to do.

---

Instead I'd suggest that we relax the constraint on the `E` properties and use the intentionally "anything-goes" type of [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any):

```
/* type ValidationFor<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Validation<T[K], any> }; */
```

That works; `ValidationFor<StudentSchema>` would match the values you want, but it's too "forgetful"; since it will use `any` instead of the actual `E` property you give it.  In order to make the compiler remember, we make a [generic](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) helper function that just takes a value of a generic type that `extends ValidationFor<StudentSchema>`:

```
const valsForStudentSchema =
    <U extends { [K in keyof StudentSchema]: Validation<StudentSchema[K], any> }>(
        valMap: U
    ) => valMap;
```

If you pass an argument to `valsForStudentSchema()` that does not match `ValidationFor<StudentSchema>`, you'll get an error.  If you pass an argument that *does* match, the compiler will just return it without widening it to `ValidationFor<StudentSchema>` and forgetting.

Like this:

```
const StudentValidations = valsForStudentSchema({
    name: {
        foo: 'AAA',
        bar: 1,
        validation: (errorMessages?: { required: string }): SchemaValidation<string> =>
            new StringSchemaValidation()
                .setIsRequired(errorMessages?.required),
    },
    id: {
        foo: 'BBB',
        bar: 2,
        validation: (errorMessages?: { required: string; match: string; max: (max: number) => string }): SchemaValidation<string> =>
            new StringSchemaValidation()
                .setIsRequired(errorMessages?.required)
                .setMatches(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/, errorMessages?.match)
                .setMax(30, errorMessages?.max(30)),
    },
    country: {
        foo: 'CCC',
        bar: 3,
        validation: (errorMessages?: { required: string }): SchemaValidation<string> =>
            new StringSchemaValidation()
                .setIsRequired(errorMessages?.required),
    },
    age: {
        foo: 'DDD',
        bar: 4,
        validation: (errorMessages?: { required: string }): SchemaValidation<number> =>
            new NumberSchemaValidation()
                .setIsRequired(errorMessages?.required),
    },
});
```

---

Note that you asked about having something that works with other schemas, not just `StudentSchema`.  We can do that with [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), by making a generic function that takes the schema type and returns another generic function which produces `ValidationFor` that type:

```
const validationFor = <T>() => <U extends { [K in keyof T]: Validation<T[K], any> }>(
    valMap: U
) => valMap;

const StudentValidations = validationFor<StudentSchema>()({
    // ... put the same object here as before
});
```

And you can use it with some other type like this:

```
interface Foo {
    a: boolean
}

const foo = validationFor<Foo>()({
    a: {
        foo: "",
        bar: 1,
        validation: (e?: { a: string }): SchemaValidation<boolean> =>
            new BooleanSchemaValidation()
    }
})
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgK4BMLlQgCwgFs5kBvAKGRuRDmIgC5kBnMKUAcwG5rbgWFu04he-GggD2GcFACewjtz61kcLszoZiAI2h8AvpUqhIsRCgBqcADaC4YYFJAAeACoAaZAFEAfBQSyDBSUkqi4mq6cFAsIDr6UKq0AG52Dk4uLAAU0FBSUACyEKysGiUA-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-BMXUwGQNJbFYMDIOvEUgLUVwAFU6wbXAn0nWd50XXsP3Q6CxnXU8yzcSibx-bc-xHZBDD8bIgjUZDniLFgcKCYMkLsXjD0oBDPygsAQJbephJQtDMCkkVslmWh6EYFg1LUGgQjCZAAHIAEETIMzwuNoaJYmQABGcydNSOicjyApikOTRWGOScdk2bZdnCbg2MJH8QNVfExzghyHJAaUhQiP1bS6OULKi2gADpHmWNZfJ2PYXKKbFyk8tKfK2XKans2hDEqmhBC0lLglCFgDI9VqzIaqyWAAJhqnTkMmLJZXytycU8rTkFKvyhBOCIeGQUgwEIAKxDm0g0RRNF7USIS1S4IKLhCuiwoiCKGrUGKZXQeLDsSlxktS1KMoWLKNjK3ZcigfICvcyoSteqaajOqKnqeF4iDeWMpzgABaAAvIzoYALQABmhgBOVcAGpY28YbCo8io0oWwhAYe4HEVRbIAGZkdxz7XPx361up5GagqoJqqCaRZA4RRAlSvTmoAYRF9rUs65Aqd67inKG+nvtGryJv+3Llr2wxgtDI7dtOsmaAuuLuASgaQHuvW1BBl6cvevGfuKybyt6zm1HKcaGsFwyABFvbFqKJYAFmlxzbolOWvpGoqlYd-yZsCjWDq1kPXC26Bdb1g2DQdY2YTu0nzfSzLVhVm35Yjgm-utrB2bUTmNcPCT+pz0CCgaZBpgtBVcPwx8W2IudQDI5dBxo0L3GY4cALYjigh4uA+OQAShNnos+Ak1gutbxvxTAiClIwn8OJqbIGJkmp6-dRDWA3Oid4YkVvG0ugGC0bzi+m3a2N67m5D51-K7VuaztaCuwoMrf+scVqfyCHVUB0d374lWmDAB81UQ5DWnEQ0UAdoILYpQdircT50VYIeAYFhhiVikPzYBLAIxRhAHg+CF9GqULklvW4O8KGH1UkEekVCHIewAEQCKDjQCWdkGpsIDENJWvCP7x0VDaE2rhaE+jTmTA2XpIw+mzuKM2NBjAayAA)